# Почему возникает ошибка "Unexpected token <"

Tags: reactjs

Использую reactjs первый раз в связке с yii2.
Не могу понять почему возникает такая ошибка.

```
ReactDOM.render(
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
document.getElementById('root')
```

);

Comment: Потому что jsx нужно транспилировать. Например babel-ем.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ